# OpenCSV fails to parse double quote next to each other

Tags: java, csv, parsing, opencsv

I've upgraded our OpenCSV version from 1.8 to 4.1.

With version 4.1 OpenCSV fails to parse the following lines:

```
MODIFY  ACEUD-2052  TVG00420    8806088726823   0   645.88      TV Gerät LED-LCD 140 cm (55) Samsung UE55MU6402 (1500Hz,SmartTV,4K) USB-Recording   645.88  EUR     "{""rawArticleType"":""TV Geräte/139 cm (55\"")/LCD""}"
MODIFY  ACEUD-2052  TVG00515    8806088692401   0   2397.73     TV Gerät LED-LCD 190 cm (75) Samsung UE75MU8002 (2600Hz,SmartTV,4K) USB-Recording   2397.73 EUR     "{""rawArticleType"":""TV Geräte/190 cm (75\"")/LCD""}"
MODIFY  ACEUD-2052  VG001183    4719331339302   0   103.30      VGA 2GB GIGABYTE GeForce GTX1050 D5 2G (HDMI,DP,DVI)    103.30  EUR     "{""rawArticleType"":""Grafikkarten/PCI-Express/NVIDIA""}"
```

I believe the problem is on the **(75\"")** part of the json.

OpenCSV fails with the following exception:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   java.io.IOException: Unterminated quoted field at end of CSV line.
>   Beginning of lost text: [{"rawArticleType":"TV Geräte/190 cm
>   (75"")/LCD"} MODIFY ACEUD-2052 VG001183 4719331339302 0 103.3...]

This same string is processed successfully by version 1.8

Here is the code to build the parser and reader

```
csvParser = new CSVParserBuilder()
    .withSeparator((char) (int) separatorChar)
    .withQuoteChar((char) (int) quoteChar)
    .build();

csvReader = new CSVReaderBuilder(inputStreamReader)
    .withCSVParser(csvParser)
    .build();
```

Where `separatorChar` is a TAB (int value 9) and `quoteChar` is '"', quote char, (int value 34)

The code above runs fine with version 1.8 but fails with version 4.1

On version 4.1 I see there is a `CSVParserBuilder()#withIgnoreQuotations(boolean value)`[OpenCSV4.1-Javadoc link](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/opencsv/CSVParserBuilder.html#withIgnoreQuotations(boolean))

If I set it to true then the lines are processed without exceptions but then the output is `{"rawArticleType":"Displays/60 - 61 cm (24""")/WUXGA (1920x1200)"}` which is not valid json and will be skipped by the json parser that is downstream which makes this not acceptable solution.

I also tried to set the escape char to `"` (single quote) but then OpenCSV raises an exception complaining

> java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: The separator, quote, and
>   escape characters must be different!

Again, my question is what am I doing wrong to be able to parse those strings and output valid json?

**EDIT:**

I'm reading the CSV file by using `csvReader.readNext()`